# Why Width changes after setActiveItem?

Tags: sencha-touch

I have a MainView with 'card' layout has 2 items : MenuView and TestView. When I setActive for the MenuView, it has width equal to the MainView's width which is 1280. In the next action after tap a button in menuView, I setActive the TestView, but it's width is only 0. Can anyone explain that for me ? And give me a way to set the TestView's width to 1280. 
Here is my code in sencha touch 1:

```
'Ext.regController('MainController',{
  'index': function(options){
    if (!Test.views.mainView){
        Test.views.mainView = new Test.views.MainView();
    }

    console.log('mainView width: '+ Test.views.mainView.getWidth());
    console.log('menuView width: '+ Test.views.menuView.getWidth());

    Test.views.mainView.setActiveItem(Test.views.menuView);
},

'start': function(options){
    console.log('testView width: '+ Test.views.testView.getWidth());
    Test.views.mainView.setActiveItem(Test.views.testView);
}
});

Test.views.MainView = Ext.extend(Ext.Panel, {
  fullscreen : 'true',
  layout : 'card',
  cardSwitchAnimation : 'slide',
  initComponent : function (){
    Ext.apply(Test.views, {
        menuView: new Test.views.MenuView(),
        testView: new Test.views.TestView()
    });

    this.items = [Test.views.menuView, Test.views.testView]

    Test.views.MainView.superclass.initComponent.call(this);
}
    });

   Test.views.MenuView = Ext.extend(Ext.Panel,{
initComponent: function(){
    this.startButton = new Ext.Button({
        text: 'Start',
        ui: 'action',
        scope: this,
        handler: function(){
            Ext.dispatch({
                controller: Test.controllers.mainController,
                action: 'start'
            });
        }
    });

    this.exitButton = new Ext.Button({
        text: 'Exit',
        ui: 'action',
        scope: this,
        handler: function(){
        }
    });

    this.items = [this.startButton, this.exitButton]

    Test.views.MenuView.superclass.initComponent.call(this);
 }
  });

  Test.views.TestView = Ext.extend(Ext.Panel,{
   initComponent: function(){
    this.html = 'test';

    Test.views.TestView.superclass.initComponent.call(this);
}
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set width with setWidth();

```
Test.views.testView.setWidth('50px');
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but can you explain why my TestView's width changes to 0. I realized that the View which is actived first always has the initialize width but the second's width is 0 ??